¿Cuál es la diferencia entre redes neuronales convolucionales y recurrentes?
he tenido esta duda porque las definiciones parecen indicar que se refieren a lo mismo, pero con definiciones distintas. Me pregunto si en realidad son diferentes.

Diferencias
La principal diferencia a groso modo es que las redes convolucionales son ideales para tareas espaciales, como puede ser procesar una imagen y las recurrentes lo son para datos secuenciales como texto.
Estas son las caracteristicas principales de cada una de ellas:
Convolucionales (CNN):

Las CNN son particularmente eficaces para tareas de visión por computadora, como reconocimiento de imágenes y segmentación semántica.
Utilizan capas de convolución para detectar patrones espaciales en los datos de entrada. Estas capas convolucionales están diseñadas para aprender características locales, como bordes, texturas y formas, a través de filtros que se aplican a regiones del espacio de entrada.
Las CNN también pueden incluir capas de agrupación (pooling) para reducir la dimensionalidad y la cantidad de parámetros de la red, así como capas completamente conectadas para realizar la clasificación final.
Son inherentemente estructuras feedforward, lo que significa que la información fluye en una sola dirección, de la entrada a la salida, sin bucles o conexiones recurrentes.

Recurrentes (RNN):

Las RNN son adecuadas para tareas que implican secuencias de datos, como traducción automática, generación de texto, análisis de sentimientos y reconocimiento de voz.
Tienen la capacidad de procesar datos secuenciales al mantener estados internos que actúan como "memoria" de la red, lo que les permite modelar dependencias a lo largo del tiempo.
Cada paso de tiempo en una RNN recibe una entrada y produce una salida, además de actualizar su estado interno en función de la entrada actual y el estado anterior.
Las RNN pueden ser susceptibles a problemas de gradiente que desaparecen o explotan durante el entrenamiento debido a su estructura recurrente. Para abordar este problema, se han desarrollado variantes como las LSTM (Long Short-Term Memory) y las GRU (Gated Recurrent Units), que son capaces de mantener información a largo plazo y controlar el flujo de información.


Imagina que tienes que diseñar un sistema de visión artificial para reconocer objetos en imágenes. Para esta tarea, lo más adecuado sería utilizar una red neuronal convolucional (CNN). Estas redes están especialmente diseñadas para procesar datos con estructura de rejilla, como las imágenes. A través de operaciones de convolución y submuestreo, una CNN puede aprender a detectar patrones visuales y características locales en las imágenes, lo que la hace perfecta para tareas como el reconocimiento de objetos, la detección de rostros o la segmentación de imágenes.
Por otro lado, si tu tarea es, por ejemplo, traducir textos de un idioma a otro, una red neuronal recurrente (RNN) sería la opción más adecuada. Las RNN están optimizadas para procesar secuencias de datos, como texto o señales de audio. Gracias a sus conexiones recurrentes, estas redes pueden mantener información sobre el contexto previo a medida que avanzan en la secuencia, lo que les permite capturar dependencias a largo plazo en los datos. Esta capacidad las hace ideales para tareas como la traducción automática, el reconocimiento de voz o el análisis de sentimientos.
Mientras que las CNN se centran en patrones espaciales y estructuras de rejilla, las RNN están diseñadas para manejar secuencias temporales. Las CNN pasan la información de entrada en una sola dirección, mientras que las RNN la procesan de manera secuencial, actualizando su estado interno a cada paso de la secuencia. Esto les permite "recordar" información relevante del pasado y utilizarla para procesar los datos actuales y futuros.

Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
